# Using FiddlerCore with Selenium to capture network traffic

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, fiddler

Can someone show me a working example of how this world be achieved? I'm specifically interested in cookie data.

I've done the following, and not sure how to proceed next:

```
var sessions = new List<Fiddler.Session>();

Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
{
    Monitor.Enter(sessions);
    sessions.Add(oS);
    Monitor.Exit(sessions);
};

Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);

var driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();

var selenium = new Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, 'http://www.test.com');

selenium.Start();
selenium.Open(urlRoot.ToString());
selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
selenium.Stop();
```

Comment: You've failed to describe what problem you're having. FiddlerCore will capture cookie headers as you've configured it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to try the captureNetworkTraffic command
or use a browsermob proxy to capture the traffic.

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-there-a-capturenetworktraffic-implementation-in-selenium-2-via-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

You should make selenium go through the FiddlerCore proxy, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26323323/2546759).